# __lldb_expr_640.MyClassName error?

Tags: swift, swift2

So everything compiles in this program, but I'm really when I increment the value, it returns ***__lldb_expr_640.IncrementWatcher*** (I'm executing this in a playground). Everything compiles, so that's not an issue. Here's the code:

```
class IncrementWatcher {

  var value: Int = 0 {

    willSet {

      print("About to set value to \(newValue)")

    }

    didSet {

      if value > oldValue {

        print("Value incremented by \(value - oldValue)")

      }

    }

  }

}
```

now let's create an instance...

```
let iw = IncrementWatcher()

iw.value = 50 //returns _lldb_expr_640.IncrementWatcher
```

any ideas? Is this anything to really worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, you can ignore module names that begin with `_lldb`. Playgrounds use an LLDB (debugger) session under the hood and sometimes that implementation detail leaks through to the user interface.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was nothing to worry about.

Comment: It's not really something "leaking through" — it's your class's name.

Comment: @jtbandes I was referring to the module name (corrected above).